# Number of subgroups of order 21 in $Z_6 \oplus Z_{21}$

Tags: group-theory

My try:
Subgroups of $Z_6 \oplus Z_{21}$ will be of the form $H_1 \oplus H_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $Z_6$ and $Z_{21}$, respectively. 
Now, for subgroup of order $21$, pair of possibilities for cardinality of $H_1$ and $H_2$ are $(1,21)$ and $(3,7)$, and $Z_m$ groups have unique subgroups of given order.
So I think there are only $2$ such subgroups possible.
Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Comment: No, your first sentence "Subgroups of ... will be of form ..." is wrong, there can also be subgroups that are not of this form.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with one example

Answer (score 1):

We have

$Z_6\oplus Z_{21}\cong Z_2\oplus Z_7\oplus Z_3\oplus Z_3.$

Now we see that this group has exactly one subgroup of order 7 and
exactly $4=8/2$ subgroups of order 3.
Therefore our group has exactly $4\cdot1=4$ subgroups of order 21.

Comment: can you please explain how we got $4$ subgroups of order $3$? I can find only $2$.

Comment: The group $Z_p^n$ has exactly $(p^{n-1}-1)/(p-1)$ subgroups of order $p$.
Recall how the number of one-dimensional subspaces of vector space over a finite field is counted.